# Looking for a way to merge multiple js scripts into one for a sandboxed eletron app

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am currently developing an electron app, using typescript.
As the renderer is sandboxed for security reasons, I need to pass a single .js file to the main Window.
However, due to the script being more than 2500 lines, it is currently split in multiple imported files, as would be a normal project.
How could I then merge the js files produced by typescript into a single complete file that could be passed to the electron Window ?
I tried Webpack, but I'm starting to think this is not the tool designed to do it.

what I am looking for:

*entry.ts*

```
import { Thing } from "./Thing"
const thing = new Thing();
thing.doSomething("hello world");
```

*Thing.ts*

```
export class Thing {
    doSomething(text: string) {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

that would be processed into a single file:
*main.js*

```
class Thing {
    doSomething(text) {
        // Stuff
    }
}

const thing = new Thing();
thing.doSomething("hello world");
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: you ever figure out the best way to do this? Does webpack not work for this? I've seen it used elsewhere

Comment: Actually yes, I ended up using webpack. Though making it work with the Typescript compiler was a bitch.